# Can I create WPF DXCarousel that has all items visible in size?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, carousel

I have used DXCarousel for a while but to my knowledge, the default behavior is always making the selected item in the center front with the largest size and an item or more is not visible because of the very small scaling they use to decrease size.

All I want is simple carousel that has this behavior: the selected item is in the front with large size (this is already done) but the rest of the item in the most far behind should be visible.

A sample of the behavior I want is based on most carousel work such as this carousel in the Jeep's webpage: http://www.jeep.com/en/

That page will display 5-6 models of Jeep with carousel interface, and all of the items are visible.

**UPDATE:**

I also want the furthest item on the center. But this is somehow not doable using basic DXCarousel implementation because it depends on how many items will be displayed.

Using the function distribution sample of "Lesson 4 - Using Functions and Parameters" from DXCarousel documentation helps me, the furthest object is at the center but the orientation is somehow rotated around 90 degrees.

**UPDATE 2:**

The code from Dimitry below works nice but still the furthest item is still not quite visible while the animation is playing (while selecting). Therefore I decided it's not the behavior I like or I want to be.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can make the farthest items visible using the [CarouselPanel.OffsetDistributionFunction](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCarouselCarouselPanel_OffsetDistributionFunctiontopic) like it demonstrated in this snippet:

```
<dx:CarouselPanel Name="carouselPanel1" AttractorPointIndex="2" PathSizingMode="Stretch"
                  IsRepeat="True"
                  Width ="400" Height="150" ItemSize="100,100"
                  ItemMovingPath="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type dx:CarouselPanel}, ResourceId=Ellipse}}"
                  >
    <dx:CarouselPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type dx:CarouselPanel}, ResourceId=advancedCarouselItemStyle}}" >
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" /><!-- supress opacity animation -->
        </Style>
    </dx:CarouselPanel.Resources>
    <dx:CarouselPanel.OffsetDistributionFunction>
        <dx:LinearFunction K="0.8" B="0.1" />
    </dx:CarouselPanel.OffsetDistributionFunction>
    <Border Background="Red" />
    <Border Background="Green" />
    <Border Background="Blue" />
    <Border Background="Yellow" />
    <Border Background="Pink" />
</dx:CarouselPanel>
```

I'm using the `f(x)=0.8*x+0.1` linear function to adapt items distribution interval from the default range([0..1]) to the [0.1 ... 0.9] range.

Comment: Your code is quite nice but there's still a bug: the farthest border item is not clickable. When I click, it does nothing. Could you check it?

Comment: @eriawan: this code [works fine](http://screencast.com/t/PJOBJvqn8) to me (I'm using the latest version - v12.1.5)

Comment: ok, I'll port my code to version 12.1.5, because my current code is still in 2011.2.11. After that, I will test it first.

Comment: By the way.. Dimitry, could you make the furthest item positioned in the center, just like the one in the http://www.jeep.com/en webpage?